# Make an input required if another field has value in it in Angular 6

Tags: angular

I have one input control like :

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="UserData.FirstControl" 
  formControlName="FirstControl" 
  class="form-control"             
  maxlength="8"
>
```

And one more input control like below:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  [(ngModel)]="UserData.SecondControl" 
  formControlName="SecondControl" 
  class="form-control" 
  [required]="UserData.FirstControl.value!=''" 
  maxlength="10"
>
```

I want to make SecondControl mandatory only if FirstControl has some value entered in it. How to achieve this in Angular 6. Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you create stackblitz?

Comment: I would suggest creating a custom validator - https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#custom-validators

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `[required]="UserData.FirstControl != '' ? '' : null"`

```
<input
  [(ngModel)]="UserData.FirstControl"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  maxlength="8">

<input
  [(ngModel)]="UserData.SecondControl"
  type="text"
  class="form-control"
  maxlength="10"
  [required]="UserData.FirstControl != '' ? '' : null">
```

Comment: Didn't worked. Can you answer through reactive form ?

Answer (score 0):

would suggest this. Because you don't know if the input was touched.

```
 <input type="text" 
    [(ngModel)]="UserData.SecondControl" 
    formControlName="SecondControl" 
    class="form-control" 
    [required]="UserData.FirstControl.value!='' && UserData.FirstControl.dirty" 
    maxlength="10">
```

Answer (score 0):

you can keep watch on firstControl like this:

```
this.FirstControl.valueChanges.subscribe(
   value=>{
     if(value !=null && value!=''){
        this.SecondControl.setValidators([Validators.required]);
     }
     else{
       this.SecondControl.setValidators([])
     }
     this.SecondControl.updateValueAndValidity();
})
```